# YouTube HTML5 iframe API - How do I turn OFF autohide controls on iPad?

Tags: html, ipad, youtube-api, html5-video, youtube-javascript-api

I am embedding YouTube videos using the HTML5 iframe api, and everything seems to work great except I cannot consistently turn off the controls autohide feature. On the ipad, where the player is not flash, the controls autohide. On flash players (FF, Chrome) the controls are always shown.

Here's a JS fiddle: [www.jsfiddle.net/wrxpm](http://www.jsfiddle.net/wrxpm)

My code is:

```
var ytPlayer = new YT.Player(playerID, {
    width: width,
    height: height,
    videoId: idVideo,
    playerVars: {
        'autoplay': 0,
        'controls': 2,
        'autohide': 0,
        'showinfo': 0,
        'modestbranding': 1,
        'hd': 1,
        'wmode': 'opaque'
    }
});
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what happens on the ipad when you set autohide to '2' (fade out the progress bar but leave the controls)?

Comment: There's no difference... the controller stays hidden until you hit the play button, then it shows and fades out after about 10 seconds.